# Applescript to ping test each client prior to ssh connection

Tags: macos, list, ssh, applescript, ping

I'm trying to make an Applescript that connects to a list local ssh machines, with each connection opening in a new terminal window. Prior to attempting the ssh connection, I'd like to ping the client to see if it's available: if it is, run the ssh command, if not then iterates to the next client. When I run the script it seems to work for the first connection but then gives me `--> error number -10004` for the remaining clients (and hangs the debugger). Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
set hosts to {"10.2.0.199", "10.2.0.11", "10.2.0.91", "10.2.1.591", "10.2.0.41"}
set uname to {"asus_client01", "asrock_comp", "msi003", "gigabyte4", "intel05client"}
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of hosts
        set this_uname to item i of uname --extract individual username
        set this_host to item i of hosts as string --extract iPv4 
        set uname_host to this_uname & "@" & this_host
        set hostUp to true

        try
            do shell script "ping -c 1 -t 5 " & this_host
        on error
            set hostUp to false
            display dialog this_host & " seems to be down."
            delay 2
        end try

        if hostUp then
            do shell script "ssh " & uname_host
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `do shell script` and `do script`. The difference is that `do shell script` is part of the standard script addition and will open an non-interactive shell, execute the given string, and return stdout back to you without any help from another application like Terminal. `do shell script` should never been used in any other tell application block except itself (me) because you violate some AppleScript securities you can find in AppleScript release and technical notes. `do script` command is part of AppleScript command in the application Terminal. `do script` will enter the given string in the targeted window and execute that like you have typed in Terminal yourself. `do script` is only supported by Terminal application and can't be used outside of it.

So it's either do shell script:

```
do shell script "ping -o stackoverflow.com
```

or do script by using the Terminal

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "ping -o stackoverflow.com"
end tell
```

So the total script could look something like this:

```
set hosts to {"10.2.0.199", "10.2.0.11", "10.2.0.91", "10.2.1.591", "10.2.0.41"}
set uname to {"asus_client01", "asrock_comp", "msi003", "gigabyte4", "intel05client"}

--security check: hosts list can't be longer than uname
if (count of hosts) > (count of uname) then return

repeat with i from 1 to count hosts
    repeat 1 times -- simulate continue
        set currentAddress to item i of hosts
        set currentHostname to item i of uname

        if not ((do shell script "ping -o -t 5 " & currentAddress & "&>dev/null && echo yes || echo no") as boolean) then
            exit repeat -- continue
        end if

        tell application "Terminal"
            do script "ssh " & currentHostname
        end tell
    end repeat
end repeat
```

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying do shell script vs do script. I had no idea that redirecting the output of a ping to null would neatly evaluate as a boolean. Thanks again!