# AppleScript ping shell script always returns true

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I'm trying to make this AppleScript alert me whenever a host comes on or offline. All works fine if I change the `do shell script` line to `set connected to true`/`false`, so I know the rest of the code works. But the `do shell script` line seems to always return true. When I run it in terminal it works fine, but for some reason in the AppleScript it doesn't. Even if I set the host to a random IP address that returns false every time in terminal, `do shell script` returns true every time. I got the shell script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660631/4347749) answer.

```
on run
    set oldconnected to false
    repeat
        set connected to do shell script "ping -o -t 5 My-Host.local >/dev/null && echo yes || echo no" as boolean

        if connected and not oldconnected then
            display notification "Device has connected"
        end if

        if not connected and oldconnected then
            display notification "Device has disconnected"
        end if

        set oldconnected to connected
        delay 5
    end repeat
end run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some brackets around the do call. Replace:

```
set connected to do shell script "ping -o -t 5 My-Host.local >/dev/null && echo yes || echo no" as boolean
```

with:

```
set connected to (do shell script "ping -o -t 5 My-Host.local >/dev/null && echo yes || echo no") as boolean
```

and you should be good to go!